# DNS and Internet connection broke after uninstalling docker

Tags: debian, systemd, dns, network-interface, internet

I've been having a brutal issue with connecting to the internet on my debian stretch computer. The weirdest thing is that every time I start my computer in able to connect to websites (google or github) but then eventually (say 30 seconds later) I get a server not found error on firefox.

I think something with the DNS broke because of the following:

Currently I am able to `ping 8.8.8.8` however `ping google.com` results in either `Name or service not know` or `Temporary Failure in Name Resolution`. `ping 172.217.0.0` works. Wget ing the same address redirects to google and its unable to resolve the host address.

I believe the issue stated because of Docker, since the iptables were being set to drop the forward chain. However I might be wrong here. My internet was working fine until I restarted my computer and this morning it wouldn't connect.

Regardless I tried [resetting the iptables](https://serverfault.com/a/633623) however every time I restarted they would be edited again. So I removed all Docker images, containers, and docker and containerd. However the issue remained even after I uninstalled them. So I think some docker script or something it installed stayed there.

What I have tried:

- Currently my iptables are set to accept everything.
- I added `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` to `/etc/resolv.conf`
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has `hosts: files dns`
- I am able to receive an IP address
- The issue is not the router because my other devices work.
- The hardware is fine because my window partition works fine.

I've tried looking at systemctl but that utility is new to me so I couldn't figure much out here.

`/etc/network/interfaces` has `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*` but that directory is empty.

Then it says:

`auto lo`

`iface lo inet loopback`

I don't know what else to try and I would really appreciate your help

*Edit 1:* I tried using ethernet but it's showing the same behavior

Comment: The fact that your `/etc/network/interfaces` is mostly empty is a good sign, because that probably means you have NetworkManager installed. Can you run the command `nmcli`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this default for your `nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

What are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`? Are they both your DNS servers? You only need to put your DNS servers to `resolv.conf`. Usually, it is your Router, not your provider's DNS servers.

Sometimes such a problem can be due to IPv6. So you could try to disable IPv6 on your router.

Try `ip address` to check IPv4/IPv6 on your interfaces.

`ip route` will show you actual routings.

I have docker on stretch and have no such problems.

**UPD1**

If you want to use only Google DNS servers comment out other lines in `/etc/resolv.conf`. DNS requests will be sent to the first found nameserver.

`ip` - is a command, `address` and `route` are options

`ip address` - lists your network interfaces with configured IPv4(inet) and IPv6(inet6) addresses. You can check are there any duplications or wrong netmask.

`ip route` - 'default' shows your main traffic;

check do you have a connection to Google DNSs with the command:

`telnet 8.8.8.8 53` - must connect to the server ("Connected to 8.8.8.8")

Run `host -v google.com`

find lines "Received ... bytes from [host]" to understand what host processes your DNS request.

If you have Wi-Fi enabled switch it off. There are problems with some Wi-Fi adapters on `stretch` using kernel 4.9.

Comment: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are Google's DNS. It's ok to either write them in the router DNS configuration or in your `resolv.conf`.

Comment: Hello @OleksiiMLD changing the hosts file didn't work. As Maik93 pointed out those are Google's DNS servers.  How would I check using ip address? Which command should I run for ip route?

Comment: @Dan The first line is from `nsswitch.conf`. I added an update to the post, read it.